# XMLHttpRequest, not replace contents in a div

Tags: javascript, html, xmlhttprequest

```
function loadXMLDoc()
{
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","loadnews.php",true);
xmlhttp.send();
}

<div id="myDiv"></div>
<button type="button" onclick="loadXMLDoc()">Load More News</button>
```

How i can use the XMLHTTPREQUEST to refresh a news-blog page, i have try this above but this above works OK the first time, the second replace the contents, me i dont want to replace or delete the previews contents, but to put new contents in a new line for example after a 'br' or a 'hr',  how i can do this? thx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is -

```
document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML += xmlhttp.responseText;
```

If you want to add `br` in between then -

```
document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML + '</br>' + xmlhttp.responseText;
```

EDIT:

For showing the loading sign you can use JQuery plugin [Malsup/blockui](https://github.com/malsup/blockui/). It is very easy to use. Here is detailed [documentation](http://jquery.malsup.com/block/) for the same.

Comment: this it is working, but is any way to load a gif image while the contents is loading? if not its ok for me.

Comment: i have find to way to put the loading, its ok now.